# Kotlin file Opening from Jar instead of Project : IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, kotlin

Currently, I am working on a multi-module project, wherein I have started facing an issue, for one of my modules, when I navigate to src->package path and then open a kotlin file (*.kt), as soon as I click on "Scroll from Source", it shows that the file is loaded from one of the jar in m2 repo.

I have tried to:

- unload and reload the module
- invalidate the cache and restart
- delete m2 folder completely and reimport dependencies

none of these have worked so far.

also to stress :

- this issue I am facing is only for one of the modules
- and also for only kt files, java files and other files are navigating fine.

Comment: Did you specify the dependency in the module setting? Is there any other way (gradle, maven) IntelliJ IDEA should know about the connection?

Comment: Sounds like the dependency is defined as a jar dependency rather than a project dependency. Are you using Maven/Gradle/Ant or a manually configured project?

Comment: we are using maven for dependency management... all the dependencies get downloaded from internal nexus unless we specify a snapshot version....

Comment: however, my issue is not with navigating from a module having the dependency to the dependent module... I am directly navigating to the dependent module through project structure at the left.... when I double click and open a kotlin file... it shows it well... but then as I click on "Scroll from  Source" it shows that the kt file opened does not belong to file in project directory but from one of the jar in majen.. which is a generated jar of the same project.